# Why is installing GnuCash requiring so much additional space?

Tags: software-installation, lubuntu, 15.04

```
After this operation, 276 MB of additional disk space will be used.
```

Most programs so far have only required up to 20 MB at most.

Comment: Add the full output, please.

Comment: @muru Okay, but I forgot how to put it as a code block - is it backticks?

Comment: Select the text and press Ctrl-K. But nevermind, from Tim's post I can see it has a lot of dependencies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I see:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed
  gnucash gnucash-common gnucash-docs guile-2.0 libaqbanking-data
  libaqbanking34 libaqbanking34-plugins libaqebics0 libaqhbci22
  libaqofxconnect7 libcrypt-ssleay-perl libdate-manip-perl libdbi1
  libfinance-quote-perl libgoffice-0.8-8 libgoffice-0.8-8-common
  libgwengui-gtk2-0 libgwenhywfar-data libgwenhywfar60
  libhtml-tableextract-perl libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0 libktoblzcheck1c2a
  libofx4 libosp5 libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 libwebkitgtk-1.0-common libxmlsec1
0 to upgrade, 27 to newly install, 0 to remove and 39 not to upgrade.
Need to get 115 MB of archives.
After this operation, 270 MB of additional disk space will be used.
```

I count 33 things being installed - and 270 / 33 is about 8.2 MB per thing being installed.

So why does it need these things? The developers based some features on already existing packages. This saves time, money and (indirectly) storage space.

Imagine if you installed 5 programs, each requiring a different program to the others that does the same thing. That's maybe 50MB when it could have been 10.

In this case, none of the "extras" have been installed before, and so you have to install them all.

In total, the programs that don't have "gnucash" in the name are 86 MB - so the 3 programs `gnucash`, `gnucash-common`, and `gnucash-docs` are together about 185 MB. This may seem a lot, but the program does do a lot of things!

Comment: Of which 150MB is the documentation. OP should probably use `--no-install-recommends`.

Comment: Documentation and language packages often take up a lot more space than the program it self